# Typo in the Terms of Service

Tags: discussion, legal, spelling, terms-of-service, askubuntu

I found a typo in  the Terms of Service, section 4.

> When accessing the askubuntu.com, meta.askubuntu.com, or chat.askubuntu.com sites ("AskUbuntu"), Subscriber will also abide by the most current Ubuntu Code of Conduct, which can be found at http://www.ubuntu.com/community/conduct, and is hereby incorporated by reference, but solely with regard to AskUbuntu.

Source: https://stackexchange.com/legal

The name of the site is Ask Ubuntu, as stated in the [Trademark Guidance](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance).

**Disclaimer:** I am not a lawyer, and this is not legal advice.

Comment: That language creates an alias for the purposes of the terms.  As long as the terms spell that alias consistently, it's "correct", regardless of whether it agrees with any verbiage used outside the terms.

Comment: Indeed. "A" would be correct too legally seen.